# Is there a way for me to detect if property is being used?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created custom textfield so i can easily change its styling in one place.

Here is my custom textfield:

```
class CustomTextFieldOutline extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextFieldOutline(
      {Key key,
      this.label,
      this.controller,
      this.isValid,
      this.invalidMsg,
      this.obscureText,
      this.onTapPasswordVisibility,
      this.formatter})
      : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool isValid;
  final String invalidMsg;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Function onTapPasswordVisibility;
  final List<TextInputFormatter> formatter;

  @override
  _CustomTextFieldOutlineState createState() => _CustomTextFieldOutlineState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldOutlineState extends State<CustomTextFieldOutline> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.label,
          errorText: widget.isValid ? null : widget.invalidMsg,
          errorStyle: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
          errorBorder: underlineInputBorder,
          focusedErrorBorder: underlineInputBorder,
          enabledBorder: underlineInputBorder,
          focusedBorder: underlineInputBorder,
          suffixIcon: (widget.obscureText != null)
              ? GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    widget.onTapPasswordVisibility();
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    widget.obscureText
                        ? Icons.visibility_off
                        : Icons.visibility,
                    color: constant.colorWhite,
                  ),
                )
              : null),
      style: TextStyle(color: constant.colorWhite),
      controller: widget.controller,
      obscureText: (widget.obscureText != null) ? widget.obscureText : false,
      inputFormatters: (widget.formatter != null) ? widget.formatter : null,
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how i call it:

```
CustomTextFieldOutline(
  label: constant.password,
  controller: _passwordSignUpController,
  isValid: _isPasswordValid,
  invalidMsg: _passwordValidMsg,
  obscureText: _isHidePassword,
  onTapPasswordVisibility: () {
    setState(() {
      _isHidePassword = !_isHidePassword;
    });
  },
)
```

Here is my question. How can i detect if onTapPasswordVisibility property is being used or not so that i can do checking either to use GestureDetector or not. Something like this:

```
suffixIcon: (widget.onTapPasswordVisibility != null)
? GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    widget.onTapPasswordVisibility();
  },
  child: Icon(
    widget.obscureText
        ? Icons.visibility_off
        : Icons.visibility,
    color: constant.colorWhite,
  ),
)
: null)
```

Comment: Have you tried testing your attempt? (Checking for null) Were there any errors?

Comment: It is not error when i use widget.obscureText to do the checking. But i am thinking maybe using widget.onTapPasswordVisibility will be better since it does not depend on another property.